# When I change from instance to class method, why is 'self' no longer allowed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class-method, class-members

I'm afraid this is a stupid question, but I honestly don't understand.

I have a class, `RemoteConfiguration` and currently it's functionality is all instance methods. This being so, I have to use it like:

```
RemoteConfiguration* configs = [[RemoteConfiguration alloc] init];
[configs updateSettings];
[configs release];
```

This is annoying because there is no need to create an object just to use one method which could be a class method and called like:

```
[RemoteConfiguration updateSettings];
```

But when I change my methods from `-` to `+` Xcode complains about every object I access with `self`, suggesting that I use `->` instead. (Which also causes a warning)
I don't get this. Regardless of the methods, the object will still have its member variables. So why is `->` necessary? And how can I use member variables in class methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within a class method, the keyword `self` doesn't refer to an instance of that class type, but rather the actual `class` instance, as in the result of `[RemoteConfiguration class]`.

Class instances like this **do not have instance variables** (at least not the ones you're declaring, but rather the `Class` instance variables, most notably the `isa` instance variable).

If you wish to have a single static instance of `RemoteConfiguration` you can declare the instance variables as `static` variables within the `.m` file, or use something like the [singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like) to keep an instance handy.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code it sounds like you are referencing `self` from within the method that you want to be a class method.

You cannot reference `self` because you are performing an action on the class, not an instance of the class. Hence `self` does not refer to what expect.

You'll have to modify the method if you truly seek it to be a class method. Keep in mind, you'll only have local variables and `static` variables to work with. If you have any properties or instance variables you wont have access to those either.

Comment: See Benoit's answer as its a little more detailed then my own. And he goes into the singleton pattern which will definitely help

Answer (score -4):

“self” points to the instance. A class method does not have any instance associated with it.

Basically, if you call a class method, “the object” that “will still have its member variables” is not “seen” by the method, because it’s a method on the class as a whole, not on specific individual objects.

You can probably pass one to it – but then, why use a class method in the first place? (In short: don’t.)

There’s also the possibility to use class variables instead of instance variables, in theory… it all depends.

Comment: This is incorrect. `self` inside of a class method refers to the `class` instance. For example, `[[self alloc] init]` is valid code inside a class method.

Comment: I think alloc is somewhat special here, as it requires the class. His example, on the other hand, refers to *instance* variables.

Comment: @mirabilos there is absolutely nothing special about +alloc.  Class methods have a `self` and that `self` refers to the class as Benoit said.

Comment: Yes, but that’s precisely what I was saying: the “self” of a class method is not the same as the “self” of an instance method, which is an object, not the class itself. I admit being a bit confused about alloc, yes it’s not special.